# regex to take data from brackets

Tags: regex

Below is String

```
insert into data (name, Id, address) values (?,?,?)
```

I tried below regex but it gives data with brackets,

```
\((.*?)\)
```

also it highlights both String. I need only first bracket String
as Output 
Expected output :-

```
name, Id, address
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might use a character set to match word characters, commas, and spaces only (exclude question marks), with lookahead for `)` at the end:

```
[\w, ]+(?=\))
```

https://regex101.com/r/nit60q/2

Comment: Its working fine.what about lookbehind? if I want to for last bracket. just for my understanding. i I want output like ?,?,?

Comment: Sure, if your environment supports lookbehind you can add `(?<=\()` to the beginning. If the parentheses are balanced, it's unnecessary, but it *will* speed up the regex's performance.

Comment: If you want the question marks as well, then just include them in the character set. `[\w, ?]`

Comment: Thanks. is it right to get ?,?,?  from above string  regex-  [\w, ]+(?<=\()

Comment: parentheses  are always balance

Comment: Add the lookbehind to the *beginning* to check the `(` : `(?<=\()[\w, ?]+(?=\))` https://regex101.com/r/nit60q/3

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178834/discussion-between-raje-and-certainperformance).